# SvelteKit "TypeError: value must be a string or TypedArray" in hash Function

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I'm encountering a problem in my SvelteKit application where an error is thrown in SvelteKit's internal hash function, located in @sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/hash.js. The error message is TypeError: value must be a string or TypedArray.
Here is a simplified version of the code that seems to be causing the issue:

```
// +layout.ts
async function createFavorites(user : User, fetch : any) {
    let favLinks : Link[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i<1; i++) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('id', JSON.stringify(user.settings.favorites[i]));

        let response = await fetch('/links?/getLink', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        if (response) {
            let text = await response.text();

            const link : ActionResult = deserialize(text);

            if (link.type == 'success' && link.data) {
                favLinks.push(link.data.link)
            }
            else  {
                if (dev) console.error(`Error with fetching link with ID ${user.settings.favorites[i]}: `, link.data);
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('id', JSON.stringify(user.settings.favorites[i]));

                let res = await fetch('/user?/deleteFav', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                });

                if (dev) {
                    const resData = deserialize(await res.text());

                    if (resData.type == 'failure')
                        console.error(`Error with fetching deleteLink with ID ${user.settings.favorites[i]}: `, resData.data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return favLinks;
}


export const load = (async ({ data, fetch }) => {
    if (data && data.user) {
        await createFavorites(data.user, fetch);
    }
});
```

```
// +layout.server.ts
export const load = (async ({ locals }) => {
    const { user } = locals;

    return { user };
});
```

Here, the load method in +layout.ts calls function createFavorites. This function returns favLinks which doesn't appear to be the cause of the issue since the error persists even when nothing is returned.
However, if I do not call createFavorites, the error doesn't occur.
Could someone help me understand why executing createFavorites causes this issue, and what I might do to resolve it?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why the heck are you posting to form actions all over the place in a ***load*** function?

Comment: @H.B., I wanted to load the user-settings from the backend (database) into a Svelte store. But when I did this in the +layout.server.ts without the fetches, the store wasn't populated with data in the frontend.

Comment: That does not explain any of this. For one thing there is logic here that deletes data, in a ***load*** function. And as noted, these are *form actions* which, as the name implies, should be triggered by forms. If you want to set up a store, do it in the page/layout component (i.e. the `.svelte`), the load function should just get the user data itself.